# how operating system(linux) kills java program ? What happens to the jvm when I hard kill a java process?

Tags: java, linux, operating-system

Suppose I hard kill a java process by issuing the command kill -9 pid, will the jvm come to a halt or will it run garbage collector and reclaim memory in heap and then stop the execution.

Comment: It would die immediately, nothing from you said would happen.

Comment: Even if you call `System.exit` it wont normally run the garbage collector. In that case shutdown hooks will get called, but there's no need to release memory or OS resources if the process is going away anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yeah - it's just the same as killing any process.  The OS removes execution from all running threads and releases all resources used, memory etc.  The JVM, and what it may have been running, just ceases to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process you're killing is the JVM process, which is running your Java code. So it has no chance to do anything at all.

Naturally, since the heap is memory that was allocated to the process, it's returned to the system's free memory pool—but not by the JVM, by the standard Linux mechanism of killing a process.

Comment: Thanks T.J for the answer